# jQuery: Multiple event handlers one submit button

Tags: jquery

I have a form with a disabled submit button.

The submit button will only be enabled once the validation checks are successful for both event handlers.

How do I achieve this using **only jQuery** and **without modifying the event handlers** (e.g. using .change() only instead of .change() and .keyup())? I am aware that my current code will enable the submit button so long as validation checks within 1 event handler is successful.

I read that it is best to share jQuery code via jsfiddle so I am doing so here:
https://jsfiddle.net/Ebbinghaus/u5mozhx9/4/

```js
$(function() { //once the DOM is loaded
  $("input[type=submit]").prop('disabled', true) //disable the submit button

  //Name Validation
  $("input#movName").keyup(function(event) { //while listening for a keyup in input#movName
    var name = $("input#movName").val().trim(); //get the movie description value
    $("div#divMessage").html("*denotes compulsory fields" + "<br><br>"); //show the div#Message content
    $("div#divMessage").prepend("Number of characters used: " + name.length + "/10" + "<br><br>") //

    if (name.length < 5 || name.length > 10) { //if the movie name has less than 5 or more than 10 characters
      $("div#divMessage").append("<ul><li>Please enter a movie name between 5 to 10 characters long.</li></ul>"); //add this feedback to the div#divMessage content
      $("input#movName").css("background-color", "yellow"); //highlight the movie name input box in yellow
      $("input[type=submit]").prop('disabled', true) //disable the submit button
    } else { //else if the movie name has the correct number of characters
      $("input#movName").css("background-color", "white"); //keep the movie name input box background white
      $("input[type=submit]").prop('disabled', false) //disable the submit button
    }
  })

  //Type Validation
  $("form").change(function() { //upon hitting the submit button
    var type = $("select#movType").val(); //get the movie type value from the respective form (option) element

    $("div#divMessage").html("*denotes compulsory fields" + "<br><br>"); //show the div#divMessage content

    movList = ["horror", "comedy", "action", "sci-fi"]; //assignment 1 requirement: create a list of correct movie types
    if (!movList.includes(type)) { //if the movie list does not contain the movie type value selected
      $("div#divMessage").append("<ul><li>Please indicate whether the movie is M18-rated or not.</li></ul>"); //add this feedback to the div#divMessage content
      $("select#movType").css("background-color", "yellow"); //highlight the select list in yellow
      $("input[type=submit]").prop('disabled', true) //disable the submit button

    } else { //if the movie list does contains the movie type value selected
      $("select#movType").css("background-color", "white"); //keep the movie type select list background white
      $("input[type=submit]").prop('disabled', false) //disable the submit button            
    }
  })
})
```

```css
<style>h1 {
  color: #7157ff;
}

hr {
  display: block;
  border: 0;
  border-top: 3px solid #f90;
  padding: 0;
}

textarea {
  width: 70%;
}

#div_main {
  font-family: Sans-serif;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 30px;
  width: 500px;
}

#div_left {
  width: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

#div_left p {
  margin-bottom: 19px;
}

#div_right {
  width: 350px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}

</style>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div_main">
  <h1>
    Add Movie
  </h1>
  <hr>
  <form action="process.html" method="POST">
    <div id="div_left">
      <p>Name*:</p>
      <p>Type*:</p>
    </div>
    <div id="div_right">
      <p><input type="text" id="movName" name="movName"></p>
      <p>
        <select id="movType">
          <option> Select a Type</option>
          <option value="horror">Horror</option>
          <option value="comedy">Comedy</option>
          <option value="action">Action</option>
          <option value="sci-fi">Sci-Fi</option>
        </select>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit">
  </form>
  <div id="divMessage" name="clientFdBk">
    *denotes compulsory fields.
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have to check each element is empty or not selected on change or keyup event then if any element is not validated then disable submit button.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () { //once the DOM is loaded
            $("input[type=submit]").prop('disabled', true) //disable the submit button

            //Name Validation
            $("input#movName").keyup(function (event) { //while listening for a keyup in input#movName
                var name = $("input#movName").val().trim(); //get the movie description value
                $("div#divMessage").html("*denotes compulsory fields" + "<br><br>"); //show the div#Message content
                $("div#divMessage").prepend("Number of characters used: " + name.length + "/10" + "<br><br>") //

                if (name.length < 5 || name.length > 10) { //if the movie name has less than 5 or more than 10 characters
                    $("div#divMessage").append("<ul><li>Please enter a movie name between 5 to 10 characters long.</li></ul>"); //add this feedback to the div#divMessage content
                    $("input#movName").css("background-color", "yellow"); //highlight the movie name input box in yellow
                    $("input[type=submit]").prop('disabled', true) //disable the submit button
                } else { //else if the movie name has the correct number of characters
                    $("input#movName").css("background-color", "white"); //keep the movie name input box background white
                    if ($("select#movType").val().trim() !== "Select a Type") {
                        $("input[type=submit]").prop('disabled', false)
                        $("div#divMessage").append("<ul><li>Please Select type.</li></ul>");
                    } //disable the submit button
                }
            })

            //Type Validation
            $("form").change(function () { //upon hitting the submit button
                var type = $("select#movType").val(); //get the movie type value from the respective form (option) element
                var name = $("input#movName").val().trim();
                $("div#divMessage").html("*denotes compulsory fields" + "<br><br>"); //show the div#divMessage content

                movList = ["horror", "comedy", "action", "sci-fi"]; //assignment 1 requirement: create a list of correct movie types

                if (!movList.includes(type)) { //if the movie list does not contain the movie type value selected
                    $("div#divMessage").append("<ul><li>Please indicate whether the movie is M18-rated or not.</li></ul>"); //add this feedback to the div#divMessage content
                    $("select#movType").css("background-color", "yellow"); //highlight the select list in yellow
                    $("input[type=submit]").prop('disabled', true);

                } else { //if the movie list does contains the movie type value selected
                    $("select#movType").css("background-color", "white"); //keep the movie type select list background white

                    if (name.length > 0 && type != "Select a Type") { //if the movie name has less than 5 or more than 10 characters
                        $("div#divMessage").append("<ul><li>Please enter a movie name between 5 to 10 characters long.</li></ul>"); //add this feedback to the div#divMessage content
                        $("input#movName").css("background-color", "yellow"); //highlight the movie name input box in yellow
                        $("input[type=submit]").prop('disabled', false) //disable the submit button
                    } //disable the submit button
                }
            })
        })
    </script>
    <style>
        h1 {
            color: #7157ff;
        }

        hr {
            display: block;
            border: 0;
            border-top: 3px solid #f90;
            padding: 0;
        }

        textarea {
            width: 70%;
        }

        #div_main {
            font-family: Sans-serif;
            margin: auto;
            margin-top: 30px;
            width: 500px;
        }

        #div_left {
            width: 150px;
            display: inline-block;
            float: left;
        }

            #div_left p {
                margin-bottom: 19px;
            }

        #div_right {
            width: 350px;
            display: inline-block;
            float: right;
        }

        .clear {
            clear: both;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="div_main">
        <h1>
            Add Movie
        </h1>
        <hr>
        <form action="process.html" method="POST">
            <div id="div_left">
                <p>Name*:</p>
                <p>Type*:</p>
            </div>
            <div id="div_right">
                <p><input type="text" id="movName" name="movName"></p>
                <p>
                    <select id="movType">
                        <option> Select a Type</option>
                        <option value="horror">Horror</option>
                        <option value="comedy">Comedy</option>
                        <option value="action">Action</option>
                        <option value="sci-fi">Sci-Fi</option>
                    </select>
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit">
        </form>
        <div id="divMessage" name="clientFdBk">
            *denotes compulsory fields.
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```